# ¿Contenedor en android?

Tags: java, android

Buenos días, soy nuevo en la web, he estado trabajando con android últimamente soy novato y me preguntaba si hay alguna manera de hacer un "contenedor" en android, resulta que mi primer activity es para iniciar sesión, tengo dos edittext uno para usuario y otro para contraseña y un botón para iniciar la sesión y pasar al siguiente activity ademas de una imagen de fondo, lo que quiero es que los dos edittext y el botón se encuentren contenidos en un recuadro para que se haga contraste con el fondo, para darme a entender mejor el efecto que quiero lograr es algo similar a lo que se muestra en esta imagen pero solo con un par de edittext y un botón.

De antemano gracias por cualquier ayuda.

**[image: texto en negrita]**

Comment: Quieres crear una Activity con esos elementos o un Widget para el desktop?

Comment: Creo que primero necesitas estudiar los elementos visuales de android, por que tu pregunta es muy confusa.

Comment: Quiero crear un activity con elementos similares, lo que quiero en concreto es poder hacer un recuadro como el que se muestra en la imagen de ejemplo, que sea gris y bordes redondeados y dentro de el colocar los edittext y el boton